# How to enable debug symbols for release build in Visual Studio Community 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling

I'm trying to profile in release mode while still being able to see proper symbols in Visual Studio Community 2019 IDE. I found instructions for other VS versions, but they don't make any sense in VSC2019, please see
[How to: Debug a Release Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-debug-a-release-build?view=vs-2019)

In more detail none of the options mentioned are available e.g. the "Linker" section doesn't exist in the property pages.

Can this be done and how?

Comment: Those instructions match up with my Visual Studio 2019. Make sure you're looking at the properties for a project.

Comment: You are right. I was looking at a shared code module properties and not the project properties. Thank you very much! Still can't get the profiler symbolicated, but that's another issue.